# How to print sorted dictionary with pprint function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, pprint

I have a simple dictionary (old_d) in the form of {'stringkey': intvalue, ...} and I want to order it by value. To do that I use.

```
new_d = {k: v for k, v in sorted(old_d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])}
```

If I use print(new_d) this works, but when I use pprint(new_d) it returns me the dictionary ordered by key name and not by value. I would like to use pprint because these dictionaries have a lot of objects and the output cant't be on one line, how can I do that?

Comment: Please include a minimal, reproducible example, including inputs, outputs, and expected outputs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think `pprint` automatically sorts the dictionary key/values.

Comment: What if you use an `OrderedDict` for `new_d`?

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of `pprint` support the `sort_dicts` argument (defaults to `True` for backward compatibility):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> d = {"foo": "bar", "baz": "quux"}
>>> pprint(d)
{'baz': 'quux', 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> pprint(d, sort_dicts=False)
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'quux'}
```

Older versions do not have this because it was based around the fact that dictionaries are unordered in older python versions, so it would sort the keys alphabetically given that the order was arbitrary anyway.  In python >= 3.7, dictionaries are in insertion order, so this is the order obtained with `sort_dicts=False`.

There was unfortunately a lag of one python version between when dictionaries were ordered and when `pprint` caught up with this fact.  Here is the above repeated but in Python 3.7:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> d = {"foo": "bar", "baz": "quux"}
>>> pprint(d, sort_dicts=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: pprint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort_dicts'
```

Answer (score 1):

`pprint()` has a keyword argument `sort_dicts` which solves your problem, but it is only available since python 3.8 version.